Number of zeros in multivariable polynomials
A polynomial $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{\alpha\in S}c_\alpha x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_n^{\alpha_n}$, where $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\in\mathbb{N}^n$, has degree $\max_{\alpha\in S}\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n$.
Suppose such a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$ has degree at most $d$, then a result says that the number of zeros of this polynomial is at most $dp^{n-1}$.
I come up with a proof different from the one in a lecture note and is much shorter. Can anyone help check if it is correct?
Proof: By induction on $n$. The result is true when $n=1$. For larger $n$, we set $x_n=i$, then $f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},i)$ is of degree at most $d$ and thus has at most $dp^{n-2}$ zeros. Each of them conjugated with $i$ form a zero of the original $f$. And each zero of $f$ can be obtained in such a way. Thus $f$ has at most $p\cdot d p^{n-2}$ zeros.

What happens if $f(x_1, \dotsc, x_{n-1},i)$ becomes the zero polynomial?

I see the problem and understand why the proof is longer: it is possible that $x_n$ can be factored out from $f$ so that setting $x_n=0$ makes the whole thing 0. So the statement is not strict: one should exclude the zero polynomial.
